# Placeholder code used for IE8 causing dropdown login field to lose focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

I am using the below placeholder code for `IE8`, however about 70% of the time when you move your mouse around in the dropdown login field it loses focus (the whole dropdown login field vanishes); through debugging - when I remove this code the problem goes away - I have found the cause of the problem is this code:

**Edit:** I have found it isn't caused by any particular placeholder code, but it IS caused by some part of the process as I have tried 3 separate placeholder plugins and it happens on all 3 of them; take them away and no problems.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if ( !("placeholder" in document.createElement("input")) ) {
        $("input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]").each(function() {
            var val = $(this).attr("placeholder");
            if ( this.value == "" ) {
                this.value = val;
            }
            $(this).focus(function() {
                if ( this.value == val ) {
                    this.value = "";
                }
            }).blur(function() {
                if ( $.trim(this.value) == "" ) {
                    this.value = val;
                }
            })
        });

        // Clear default placeholder values on form submit
        $('form').submit(function() {
            $(this).find("input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]").each(function() {
                if ( this.value == $(this).attr("placeholder") ) {
                    this.value = "";
                }
            });
        });
    }

});
```

You can view an example here: http://condorstudios.com/stuff/temp/so/header-sample.php

**Edit:** Not sure if it will help as jsfiddle doesn't work on IE8 and I can't test if the fiddle behaves badly in IE8 too, but here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m8arw/7/

Any way to fix this?

Comment: One interesting thing which i notice is, if we move slowly over the login field/overlay, then it doesn't loose focus. Not solve your issue, but might indicate that there might be some css issue.

Comment: I've had good luck with Mathias Bynens placeholder: `https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder` -- you might give that a try.

Comment: I also suggest you fix this error in scripts.js:56 in your example: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'screwDefaultButtons'`

Comment: @yitwail Thanks - I may have to try another placeholder plugin if worst comes to worst; wanted to avoid it though as went though a few before setting on this one.

Comment: @yitwail Don't worry about that bug, just a sample page I srapped together to show this issue - probably just took out some JS includes. :)

Comment: Might be worth creating a JSFiddle for it - that will make it easier to debug the issue

Comment: @Brett - you need to make a working example in jsbin or jsfiddle so others can help you. You're question is not exactly clear on what element is disappearing/losing focus when you move the mouse. Is it the 'placeholder text' that's disappearing? the entire dropdown box? the whole input field?

Comment: Alright - I will set one up; I didn't do it originally as jsFiddle doesn't even work on IE8 so didn't see the point.

Comment: @Brett The [draft](http://blog.jsfiddle.net/doc-testing-on-mobile) feature of jsfiddle allows one to use view stuff in unsupported browsers. That link explains things in terms of mobile but it also applies to unsupported browsers.

Comment: I have found it isn't caused by any particular placeholder code, but it IS caused by some part of the process as I have tried 3 separate placeholder plugins and it happens on all 3 of them; take them away and no problems.

Comment: As I said, it has nothing to do with that js...

Comment: Have you tried adding "js/html5shiv.js" before "js/scripts.js"?

Comment: It *might* be time to start to consider ending support for IE8... Windows Vista can run IE9, and Microsoft is ending support for Windows XP in a couple of weeks. Chrome is still offered on Windows XP (for now) and is a more standards-compliant browser than IE8 ever was, anyway.

Comment: @Brett: see my code and demo...

Comment: @Binod I tried that but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried switching your event to show/hide dropdown to 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave'?
It's a lot more reliable on old IE than 'focus' and 'blur' event. Also, bind the event directly on the 'dropdown' div is more preferable than on the 'input' element.

In short, please try change this part of your code like this.

```
$(function() {
    var dropdown = $('div.login div.dropdown')
        .on('mouseenter', function() {
            dropdown.css('display', 'block');
        })
        .on('mouseleave', function() {
            dropdown.removeAttr('style');
        });
});
```

Comment: I had to keep the second block of code from coma's answer where it was to keep the issue from happening as explained in my comment to him; but I added your code inside the `if ( !("placeholder" in document.createElement("input")) ) {` block and it worked!!

Answer (score 1):

> - **demo:** http://so.devilmaycode.it/placeholder-code-used-for-ie8-causing-dropdown-login-field-to-lose-focus

```
$(function(){
    $('#main_header .login li').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('.dropdown').show();
    },function(){
        $(this).find('.dropdown').hide();
    });
});
```

> - **NOTE:** i have also cleaned up and fixed some coding horror in your js code...

Comment: Doesn't that just replace the css that is used to show the dropdown on hover with JS code?

Comment: @Brett: my answer is the same of the accepted one, yes it replace / force the css to work observing the pointer position better then IE8 does itself. plus i have cleaned up your code for better performance.

Comment: Oh ok.... I wasn't sure and wanted to accept an answer before the time ran out for me to accept a answer for my bounty.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to implement placeholder on all browsers (it uses Modernizr to detect it):

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/S3zQ9/

```
var placeholder_OnBlur = function () {
    var input = $(this);

    if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
        input.addClass('placeholder');
        input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
    }
};

var placeholder_OnFocus = function () {
    var input = $(this);

    if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
        input.val('');
        input.removeClass('placeholder');
    }
};

var placeholder_OnSubmit = function () {
    $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function () {
        var input = $(this);

        if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
            input.val('');
        }
    });
};

var placeholder_OnLoad = function () {
    if (!!$(this).attr('placeholder')) {
        $(this).on('focus', placeholder_OnFocus);
        $(this).on('blur', placeholder_OnBlur);
        $(this).parents('form').on('submit', placeholder_OnSubmit);
        $(this).blur();
    }
};

 if (!Modernizr.input.placeholder) {
     $('[placeholder]').each(placeholder_OnLoad);
 }
```

Don't have IE8 to test it, but it should work.

Comment: Couldn't all this code be placed inside something like `if (!Modernizr.input.placeholder) {` to avoid other browsers using it?

Comment: @Brett Sure it can :)